# Razor display template fails XHTML 1.0 Transitional validation

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, resharper-6.0

I am just starting with mvc3 and razor having done some mvc2 in the past and something puzzles me.

I am trying to render a unordered list from a collection in my model and have done so successfully. using this code.

In my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <ul>
        @Html.DisplayFor( m => m.SomeThings)
    </ul>
}
```

In my DisplayTemplate:

```
@model MyNamespace.Models.SomeType               
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Content(String.Format("~/SomeUrl/{0}", @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.UrlText)))">@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Name)</a>
</li>
```

This all works and is fine but I've noticed that the display template fails XHTML 1.0 Transitional validation and thus generates a warning (Element 'li' cannot be nested within element li') this is annoying as its not nested but is there anyway to stop this error ? Or is it something i must put up with ?

Comment: Either you are trying to validate a razor template (which isn't XHTML, so you shouldn't try to validate it as such) or you need to show us the XHTML you are generating from it that is failing validation.

Comment: looks like resharper is trying to do this, anyone know how to stop it or do i report a bug in resharper its definately NOT embedding <li> tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code looks fine to me, I've noticed also that the templates try to get validated, I learned to live with it, resharper reports that everything is ok but just shoes a green hint rather than an error, since it is trying to validate something as XHTML which is not then you are ok to leave it.